# How to ignore parent URL in asp.net redirects

Tags: asp.net, redirect

We have a website where by we need to redirect all the child urls of a site, but not the top level, i.e.

www.domain.com/products/some-product-page redirects to www.domain.com/some-product-page

That's all well and good. However, we have a page that exists on www.domain.com/products, and this page is being redirected to the site homepage.

I've tried two methods to try and resolve this. The first, using negate to ignore the top level /products url. But this also causes the urls underneath that to be ignored.

```
<rule name="Redirect Products child pages" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^products/(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(/*)/?.*" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^products" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent"  url="{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

I've tried variations on that pattern input with little success.

The second method I looked was creating a rule that looked just for the /products/ url, and stopped processing the rules, when found. But this also has the same effect as the first method.

```
<rule name ="Prevent Products page redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/products/" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="None" />
        </rule>
```

So is there something I need to add, to the pattern, to make it ignore all the other URLs, or am I missing something else?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. My second method worked; just required a little tweak. Like so:

```
<rule name ="Prevent Products page redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/products[/]$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect Products child pages" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^products/(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^(/*)/?.*" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent"  url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```